# php GET_ multiple

Tags: php, get, lang

Hello guys im sorry but i am newbie to php, in my site i have multiple language with GET.. Example  `site.com/index.php?lang=en` to the nav menu i have a code like this

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    // Returns a string if the URL has parameters or NULL if not
    if ($query) {
        $url .= '&lang=';
    } else {
        $url .= '?lang=';
    }
?> 
<li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>en">
```

My problem is when the lang is set. Example site.com/index.php?lang=en  when the user change the lang adds the lang to site.com/index.php?lang=en&lang=gr  .

I want to "replace" the lang and not have a url like site.com/index.php?lang=gr&lang=en&lang=en&lang=en&lang=en

thank you guys

Comment: Why dont you just use `$_GET` it would be simpler and you woudl not cause the multipe parameter issue

Comment: I use $_GET. But in the future i want to have multiple $_GETs

Answer (score 1):

try this, it's manage all type of query string you can receive

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$url_without_query_string = strtok($url, '?');
$query = array();
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);
$query['lang'] = 'en';

$new_url = $url_without_query_string . '?' . http_build_query($query);
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $new_url; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If when you have a querystring passed, you check if `lang` is part of that string using `$_GET['lang']` then you can decide correctly if you want to add a new default one or use the existing one.

```
<?php
    $default_lang = 'en'

    $url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    // Returns a string if the URL has parameters or NULL if not
    if ($query) {
        // we have a querystring
        // does it contain a lang already or not
        $url .= isset($_GET['lang'] ? '' : "&lang=$default_lang";
    } else {
        // nothing in the querystring so force a lang
        $url .= "?lang=$default_lang";
    }
?> 
<li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>">
```

Comment: It's good idea, but i have 2 languages, or 3-4-5, how to add the "gr, en, ro .. etc" to the links???

Comment: Surely that is up to the user to click something which adds the correct `lang=??` to the url when they click a selection. My code just keeps the one selected, and if nothing is selected uses `en` as a default

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to usea session variable.
If an user change the language, you only overwrite de value of the session var.